# Calling form from another php

Tags: php, html

I have created a simple form that user can use for registration

[image: registration]

On the right side there's a form that will be called based on current Form(Left Side) .. so when user already finish the registration on the right, I will automatically change to Form 2 and will call another form

The form itself already finished (Ex: Form1.blade.php, From2.blade.php, etc)

My question is how do i call the form so it will shows on the right side? and when I click Form 1, Form 2 .. etc, it will show the form OnClick

I already tried to put it on the right .. but the "next" button is not working and when i click the form title (Form 1) the form will open in the new page

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.